# Failed to start Monero Full Node : Ubuntu 18 > Boron Butterfly

Tags: monerod

I started with a new machine.

I got the latest version - https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/monero-linux-x64-v0.14.1.0.tar.bz2

Put this in `/mnt/monero/.monero`.

Copied the binaries to `/usr/local/bin`.

Created the config file and the service:

**Config**

```
data-dir=/mnt/monero/.monero  
log-file=/mnt/monero/monerod.log  
max-log-file-size=0  
p2p-bind-ip=0.0.0.0  
p2p-bind-port=18080  
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0  
rpc-bind-port=18081  
rpc-login=xxx:xxx  
#confirm-external-bind=1  
restricted-rpc=1  
no-igd=1  
db-sync-mode=safe  
enforce-dns-checkpointing=1  
out-peers=64  
in-peers=1024  
limit-rate-up=1048576  
limit-rate-down=1048576
```

**Service**

```
[Unit]  
Description=Monero Full Node  
After=network.target  

[Service]  
User=xxx  
Group=xxx  

Type=forking  
PIDFile=/mnt/monero/monerod.pid  

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/monerod --config-file /home/xxx/.bitmonero/monerod.conf --detach  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then started the service:

`sudo service monerod start`

And I get:

```
● monerod.service - Monero Full Node
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/monerod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2019-10-29 08:16:41 UTC; 9s ago  
  Process: 4819 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/monerod --config-file  
 /home/graeme/.bitmonero/monerod.conf --detach (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  

Oct 29 08:15:11 systemd[1]: Starting Monero Full Node...  
Oct 29 08:15:12 monerod[4819]: 2019-10-29 08:15:12.902        I Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.1.0-release)  
Oct 29 08:15:12 monerod[4819]: Forking to background...  
Oct 29 08:15:12 systemd[1]: monerod.service: Can't open PID file /mnt/monero/monerod.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory  
Oct 29 08:16:41 systemd[1]: monerod.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.  
Oct 29 08:16:41 systemd[1]: monerod.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.  
Oct 29 08:16:41 systemd[1]: Failed to start Monero Full Node.
```

So nothing funny, simply following the documentation.

I'd like to run a node and help.

Comment: Try to run `monerod –config-file /home/xxx/.bitmonero/monerod.conf` and see if it complains about something. If you want monerod to run in the background, you must add `--detach` to your launch command.

Comment: I think it might be resource related. I ran a big server, with 4 chains, each in an attached volume. I am splitting this up now, and building 4 instances. Getting BTC and BCH up from the repos was quick, but I am running into issues compiling LTC and XMR, in terms of the instance resources. Maybe I missed something when I compiled Monero on the single box.

Comment: Getting further, Active: activating (start) since Sun 2019-10-27 19:05:41 UTC; 1min 23s ago,

But on the 3rd status request :

Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2019-10-27 19:07:15 UTC; 27s ago

.. and it keeps complaining about the PID : /mnt/monero/monerod.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory

It should create the process ID ?

Comment: Actually, running a service for monerod is not working, it might be that the daemon is not happy with the config file format. But simply running monerod with your option is fine. So I just created a cron job for `@reboot`, and `@hourly`. Simple like that.

Comment: Your service file is still wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> walletnotify=/mnt/monero/notifysitestx.sh %s
>   blocknotify=/mnt/monero/notifysitesblock.sh %s

There are no options `walletnotify` or `blocknotify`, you probably want `block-notify`.

See `monerod --help` for all the available options and syntax.

> Running the daemon with the --config flag I get...

There is no option called `--config`, it's `--config-file`.

> PIDFile=/run/monero/monerod.pid

Have you created the directory `/run/monero/` though?

> –pidfile /run/monero/monerod.pid

The parameter is wrong. It should be `--pidfile /run/monero/monerod.pid`. Note the double hyphen `--`. You make this same mistake with other parameters also.

> I am not binding p2p for now, only RPC

p2p automatically binds.

> Compiling Monero alone on a box, I had to up it to 8GB of RAM.

Monero can be compiled on a Raspberry Pi, so if you needed to increase your RAM to 8GB, you must have been seriously exhausting the RAM on other things.

**UPDATE**

After you rewriting your question, you now specify `PIDFile=...` in the service file, but you *removed* the parameter `--pidfile ...`. So you're telling `systemd` there will be a PID file, but don't tell `monerod` where to create it.

Comment: I started with a new machine.  

I got the latest nix - https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/monero-linux-x64-v0.14.1.0.tar.bz2